# Realtime Streaming per User via some Comet Server

Tags: comet, socket.io, long-polling, juggernaut

I need to design a Streaming API where each connected user might have different data per category.

Lets say two users are interested in sport(category) rss feeds from the streaming api but each user has its own filtering mechanism on the server which results in different push data sets...

By using [juggernaut](https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut) , you can stream data through categories(channels) but i couldn't find a way to filter some part of the data per category on the server side depending on user filter settings.

Answer (score 1):

Channels are usually used for filtering data i.e. one for /SPORT/FOOTBALL/PREMIERLEAGUE/MANU, another /SPORT/FOOTBALL/CHAMPIONSHIP/WESTHAM and /SPORT/GOLF/USMASTERS.

I only know of one realtime Comet server which offers additional filtering though subscriptions to the channels and that is [Caplin System's Liberator](http://www.caplin.com/caplin_liberator.php). For example (pseudocode):

```
var subscriber = new Subscriber();
var filter = "headline~transfer"; // where '~' means contains
subscriber.subscribe("/SPORT/FOOTBALL/PREMIERLEAGUE/MANU", filter, function(update) {
   // handle update
});
```

The above code would subscribe to the channel but only send updates whenever and update came in where the `headline` field contained the text `transfer`.

Another solution that appears to offer this querying functionality is [pubsub.io](http://pubsub.io). From their site:

```
// connect from node
var pubsub = require('pubsub.io').connect('hub.pubsub.io/238258');
// or the browser
var pubsub = pubsubio.connect('hub.pubsub.io/238258');

pubsub.subscribe({
    hello:{$any:['world','mundo','verden']}
}, function(doc) {
    console.log(doc);
});

pubsub.publish({hello:'world'});
```

This sort of channel querying may well be something we start to see more of.